# How to find the total derivative of implicit function in implicit function theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose that $f:U(\subset\mathbb R^m\times \mathbb R^n)\to \mathbb R^n$, where $U$ is an open set, is a continuously differentiable function such that for some $(a,b)\in U, f(a,b)=0$ and that $D_2f(a,b)$ is invertible. ($D_2f(a,b)$ is the total derivative of $f|_{(\{a\}\times \mathbb R^n)\cap U}$, where $f|_{X}$ represents restriction of f to X $\subset $ domain $f$). Then, there exist open sets $U_1\ni (a,b)$, $V\ni a$ in $U$ and $\mathbb R^m$ respectively, and a continuously differentiable map $g:V\to \mathbb R^n$ such that $f(x,g(x))=0$ for all $x\in V$.

I want to find the total derivative of $g$.

I want to write $f(x,g(x))$ as a function composition of two maps $f_1$ and $f_2$ and then apply chain rule. But I don't know how to write $f(x,g(x))$ as such composition.

If $f$ were a function on an open subset of $\mathbb R$, then chain rule application immediately gives: $f_x (x,g(x))+f_y(x,g(x))g'(x)=0$.

However, in the general case, I don't know how to get the total derivative of $f(x,g(x))$. Once that is done, I believe that the equation resulting from $f(x,g(x))=0$ can be solved for total derivative of $g(x)$.

Please help in finding the total derivative of $f(x,g(x))$.  Thanks.

Comment: $[x\mapsto f(x,g(x))]=f\circ h$ with $h(x)=(x,g(x))$, and the chain rule will give you the same result as you wrote if $f$ were a function on $\mathbb R$:  $D(f\circ h)(x)=(D_1f)(h(x))+(D_2f)(h(x))\circ(Dg)(x).$

Comment: @AnneBauval I know that is the answer. But could you please elaborate on the intermediary steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "I want to write $f(x,g(x))$ as a function composition of two maps $f_1$ and $f_2$ [...] But I don't know how to write $f(x,g(x))$ as such composition":$$[x\mapsto f(x,g(x))]=f\circ h\quad\text{with}\quad h(x)=(x,g(x)).$$
- "Please help in finding the total derivative of $f(x,g(x))$":  by the chain rule,$$\begin{align}D(f\circ h)(x)&=(Df)(h(x))\circ Dh(x)\\&=\begin{pmatrix}(D_1f)(h(x))&(D_2f)(h(x))\end{pmatrix}\circ\begin{pmatrix}{\rm id}_{\mathbb R^m}\\(Dg)(x)\end{pmatrix}\\&=(D_1f)(h(x))+(D_2f)(h(x))\circ(Dg)(x).\end{align}$$So the answer is:
  $$D[x\mapsto f(x,g(x))](x)=(D_1f)(x,g(x))+(D_2f)(x,g(x))\circ(Dg)(x).$$
- "Once that is done, I believe that the equation resulting from $f(x,g(x))=0$ can be solved for total derivative of $g(x)$": yes indeed,$$0=(D_1f)(a,b)+(D_2f)(a,b)\circ(Dg)(a)$$hence$$(Dg)(a)=-(D_2f)(a,b)^{-1}\circ (D_1f)(a,b).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I understand it now. :-)